# How is $\mathsf{RP\cap UP}$ not a class containing only unsatisfying languages?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, complexity-classes

$\mathsf{RP}$ can be deterministically defined as:

> A language $L\in\mathsf{RP}$ iff there exists a polynomial $p$ and deterministic Turing machine $M$, such that:
>
> - $M$ runs for polynomial time $p$ on all inputs,
> - $\forall x \in L$, the fraction of strings $y$ of length $p(\vert x\vert)$ which satisfy $M(x, y) = 1$ is greater than or equal to $\frac1 2$,
> - $\forall x \not\in L$, and all strings $y$ of length $p(|x|)$, $M(x, y) = 0$

In contrast, $\mathsf{UP}$ can be defined as:

> A language $L\in \mathsf{UP}$ if there exists a two-input algorithm $A$ and a constant $c$ such that:
>
> - $x \in L\Rightarrow\exists! y:${$\vert y\vert = \mathcal O(\vert x\vert^c),A(x,y) = 1$},
> - $x \not\in L\Rightarrow\not\exists y:${$\vert y\vert = \mathcal O(\vert x\vert^c), A(x,y) = 1$},
> - algorithm $A$ verifies $L$ in polynomial time.

Therefore, a satisfying $L\in\mathsf{RP\cap UP}$ would have to satisfy both:

> - the fraction of strings $y$ of length $p(\vert x\vert)$ which satisfy $M(x, y) = 1$ is greater than or equal to $\frac1 2$,
> - $\exists! y:${$\vert y\vert = \mathcal O(\vert x\vert^c),A(x,y) = 1$}

It seems these are mutually exclusive requirements. So, how does it happen that $\mathsf P$, a class containing satisfying languages, contains only such languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\mathsf{RP}$ machine and the $\mathsf{UP}$ machine don't have to be the same.
That is, there might be one machine which shows that $L \in \mathsf{RP}$, and another one which shows that $L \in \mathsf{UP}$.

As an example, every language in $\mathsf{P}$ lies in $\mathsf{RP} \cap \mathsf{UP}$. The easiest way to see this is to take the advice string to be empty, but if you insist that the advice string have size $|x|$, say, then you can construct an $\mathsf{RP}$ machine which ignores the advice and just runs the $\mathsf{P}$ machine, and a $\mathsf{UP}$ machine which runs the $\mathsf{P}$ machine and only accepts if the advice is the all-zero string.